# OpenERP 6.1 - Email template to default to html

Tags: odoo

I am trying to send an email from the partner window using the Send Mail menu on the right hand panel. 
For this I have created a template email from the configuration menu, left the body (Text) empty and filled the body (Rich/html) with:

```
<p>Some text in <b>bold</b></p>
```

When I run send mail from the partner form, the message body is desperately empty and it looks like it is defaulting the message body to the Body (Text) tab from the email template.

This is confirmed when I look at table email_template where the field subtype is always "Plain".

I tried to setup the Action window specific to my email template by setting the domain value to [('subtype','=','html')], but it doesn't change anything. I also added this code to most of the Action window domains that relate to email but it hasn't changed anything either.

Does anyone know how to default sending email in HTML format from OpenERP?

> **UPDATE**: Has anyone got a sample of HTML code that works for them, meaning they receive correctly in their email client?
>
> My issue is that if I leave the Plain Text empty within the template and have some html tags under the Rich/html, then I receive an email in format html, but it is always empty. Even the source is totally empty. I suppose there is something wrong with my html syntax. Maybe I need to double the "/" in a closing paragraph as it may be an escape character somewhere, somehow. I have tried a lots of different syntaxes but apparently not the right one.
>
> So if someone out there had some html coding that works for them and they'd 
>   be happy to share, thanks in advance!
>
> **UPDATE 2**, I have created an html template email after a quick training on the internet. I have tested my bit of code with litmus and it shows exactly what I wanted to see. I then paste this exact same bit of code into OpenERP, send the email message to my email client, identical to the one on litmus, and it is totally empty. However, it says the format is HTML. There is definitely an issue somewhere but I can't point out where. It seems OpenERP doesn't send the html code. Has anyone ever had the same issue???
>
> Here is the html basic code I have used for testing and that I pasted into OpenERP:

```
<html>
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#cccccc" cellpading="10" cellspacing="10">
        <tr valign="top" align="center">
            <td>
                <table width="500" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                                liusuhflsb
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: you can't do that in 6.1 without using third-party addons or custom code.

**Long Answer**:
OpenERP 6.1 does not provide a WYSIWYG/Rich Text editor out-of-the-box (OpenERP 7.0 introduces that)

As a result, in 6.1, only the plain text version of a template is used whenever the user can manually edit the email contents. Indeed it would be quite awkward to ask users to manually edit the source of the HTML version of the template when composing their email (no WYSIWYG).
It is the case when you're composing a new email based on a template, via the corresponding `Send Mail` side bar action, because you can modify the email before sending it.

One typical case where both the HTML/Rich Text and the plain text version of a template are used as expected is when an email template is bound to a *Marketing Campaign* step (via the `marketing_campaign` module) - because these emails are sent without any editing nor any manual user action.

> **UPDATE:**
>   If that's what you're interested in, Marketing Campaigns will
>   always send both the plain-text and HTML version of your emails
>   automatically, and the recipients' mail software will display the
>   relevant one based on user preferences (for most people it will be the
>   HTML version). However you can **not** test the templates using the
>   *Send Mail* sidebar buttons, because that will keep only the plain-text version, as explained above. There are two recommended ways
>   to test those campaign emails:
>
> 1. Use the *Preview* button on the template and select a sample record to render the template for. This will let you double-check the
>      source of the HTML that will be produced.
> 2. Test-drive your campaign putting in "manual" mode: have a dummy record enter the campaign with your email address on it, then use the
>      *Campaign Follow-up* menu to make it manually advance through the campaign steps. This is really important to validate not only your
>      email templates but also the structure of your campaign. See also this
>      [basic introduction to OpenERP Marketing Campaign](http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/openerp-managing-marketing-campaigns-with-openerp), from OpenERP
>      Community Days 2012.

There are community modules that add WYSIWYG editing capabilities to OpenERP 6.1 (search for [WYSIWYG](http://v6apps.openerp.com/?text_search=wysiwyg) on [OpenERP Apps](http://apps.openerp.com)), but I don't think they were integrated with the `email_template` module in order to enable composing Rich Text directly. Doing it wouldn't be very hard though. If you're interested, start by reading the source code of the `mail.compose.message` wizard (both the [original version of the `mail` module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py) and the [`email.template` extension](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/email_template/wizard/mail_compose_message.py)), to see how the template fields are used and where.

If you're not familiar with OpenERP development, the [developer documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/index.html#book-develop-link) of OpenERP and the [technical memento](http://doc.openerp.com/memento/) will be interesting starting points.

Comment: My objective is to automate Marketing Campaign emails based on a template email. I don't mind not seeing the result of the html within OpenERP. What I want to know is how do I make sure OpenERP is going to send the HTML version rather than the plain text. I have made lots of tests and the most conclusive one was when I replaced "body_text" with "body_html" in the Send Mail view. Then the html code appeared rather than the plain text, and the email I received was of the format HTML rather than plain text.

Comment: @CloseISQ: thanks for the extra details, I've updated my answer to explain how Marketing Campaign emails are usually tested

Answer (score 0):

The e-mail message is sent with both contents: `plain` and `html`.
The e-mail client makes the decision to render either one, depending on it's capabilities. It it's `html` capable, it will use the HTML version, if not, the `plain` version will be rendered.

You should provide the two versions for the message in your template: `plain` and `html`.

Comment: Currently using ms outlook 2007. How can I make sure it then defaults receiing emails in html when both text and html are delivered in an e-mail?

Comment: I have configured outlook to make sure it would "read" html messages first (or at least not default to plain text as this is the only option) and all I get from openerp is plain text.

Answer (score 0):

This is over a year ago and I have given up on OpenErp because of this kind of flaws. I never got around to having OpenERP send me an automated email in HTML format, no matter what I tried. It always defaulted to text whichever email client I used. I would like to know if wome other people have managed receiving automated html email that related to a marketing campaign in OpenERP?